# Stripe Account : balance_insufficient

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am using stripe connected accounts and I am facing error of insufficient balance.I want to charge one person and divide that money to two sellers.

Error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "balance_insufficient",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/balance-insufficient",
    "message": "You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account. One likely reason you have insufficient funds is that your funds are automatically being paid out; try enabling manual payouts by going to https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/payouts.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
}
```

using this format:

```
// Using charge and transfer
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount"         => $chargeprice,
    "currency"       => "usd",
    "source"         => Yii::$app->request->post()['Order']['stripe_token'],
    // "destination" => $sellerStripeAccount->s_acount_id,
    "transfer_group" => Yii::$app->request->post()['Order']['product_id'],
));


// Create a Transfer to a connected account (later):
$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    "amount"         => $sellerprice ,
    "currency"       => "usd",
    "destination"    => $sellerStripeAccount->s_acount_id,
    "transfer_group" => Yii::$app->request->post()['Order']['product_id'],
));


$transfer = \Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    "amount"         => $adminammount,
    "currency"       => "usd",
    "destination"    => $adminStripeAccount->s_acount_id,
    "transfer_group" => Yii::$app->request->post()['Order']['product_id'],
));
```

I am using sandbox account. help?

Answer (score 2):

You can not transfer funds that you don't have yet. When you create a charge, it takes time for the funds to become available (2 days in the US).

This is covered in details in the documentation and Stripe explains how to link the Transfer to the original charge's availability schedule using `source_transaction`: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability

Comment: thnxs for replying...Is it possible to test this functionality in sandbox account?

Comment: Use the test card documented here https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses `4000000000000077`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.

as koopajah said:

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers#transfer-availability

adding this :

```
  "source_transaction" => "{CHARGE_ID}",
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Where does the source_transaction come from?